# Bash output stream write to a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

so i am running this on bash:

```
# somedevice -getevent
```

What this command does is it just keeps running, and everytime my device sends a certain data, say it detects change in temperature, it outputs something like this

```
/dev/xyz: 123 4567 8910112238 20
/dev/xyz: 123 4567 8915712347 19
/dev/xyz: 123 4567 8916412345 22
/dev/xyz: 123 4567 8910312342 25
/dev/xyz: 123 4567 8910112361 18
/dev/xyz: 123 4567 8910112343 20
```

And this just keeps running and as soon as it has any cause it outputs something. So there is no end to execution.

No the echo is working perfectly, however when i am trying to use the '>' operator this doesn't seem to write to file.

so for instance

```
#somedevice -getevent > my_record_file
```

this doesn't work properly, my_record_file only gets data written to it in **intervals**, however i want to be written immediately.

Any ideas?

Comment: The lag may be due to output buffering.  Can you change the program to do either do a flush() after each print or set auto-flush on its standard output?

Comment: Okay, i figured out a solution for my issue, it was a buffering issue `somedevice -getevent | grep " " --line-buffered > myrecordfile` solved the issue.. perhaps its not the best idea, but for now this hack did the job.. thanks for all you help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output is being buffered because the C standard library changes the output buffering mode depending on whether or not stdout is a terminal device.  If it's a terminal device (according to [`isatty(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty)), then stdout is *line-buffered*: it gets flushed every time a newline character gets written.  If it's not a terminal device, then it's *fully buffered*: it only gets flushed whenever a certain amount of data (usually something on the order of 4 KB to 64 KB) gets written.

So, when you redirect the command's output to a file using the shell's `>` redirection operator, it's no longer outputting to a terminal and it buffers its output.  A program can change its buffering mode with [`setvbuf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf) and friends, but the program has to cooperate to do this.  Many programs have command line options to make them line-buffered, e.g. `grep(1)`'s `--line-buffered` option.  See if your command has a similar option.

If you don't have such an option, you can try using a tool such as [`unbuffer(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer) to unbuffer the output stream, but it doesn't always work and isn't a standard utility, so it's not always available.

Answer (score 2):

The command `somedevice` probably uses the "Standard Input/Output Library", and in that library, the buffering is on by default. It is switched off when the output does to a terminal/console.

Can you modify the `somedevice` program? If not, you can still hack around it. See http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/ for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can try 'tee':

```
somedevice -getevent | tee -a my_record_file
```

The '-a' option is to append instead of just replacing the content.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your "`somedevice -getevent`" command's stdout is being block-buffered. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723795/is-stdout-line-buffered-unbuffered-or-indeterminate-by-default), stdout is by default line-buffered (i.e. what you want) if stdout is a terminal, and block-buffered otherwise.

I'd have a look at the manual for your `somedevice` command to see if you can force the output to be unbuffered or line-buffered. If not, `stdbuf -oL somedevice -getevent > my_record_file` should do what you want.