# Piping of grep is not working with tail?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I am trying to debug one scenario by checking the logs, here is my command

```
tail -f eclipse.log | grep 'enimation' | grep  -i 'tap'
```

Basically what I am trying to to is that, of all of the line, I am printing lines with enimation in it, then of all of the animation, I want to see the animation with "tap" in it.

Here is the sammple data for which it is returning empty results

```
*******enimation error*********TapExpand
*******enimation error*********TapShrink
```

This is returning empty results.

While if I run this command

```
 tail -f eclipse.log | grep  -i 'enimation.*tap'
```

it returns correct results. Can someone please explain to me, what is the difference between the above two command and why there is a discrepancy in the results. They both seem identical to me.

Comment: Definitely a duplicate of that question. But I think [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9752465/3076724) from a slightly different question actually does a better job of explaining the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`grep` is buffering it's output. To tell GNU grep to spit out output **line-by-line** you need to use `--line-buffered` option in `grep` to make it work:

```
tail -f eclipse.log | grep --line-buffered 'enimation' | grep --line-buffered -i 'tap'
```

As per `man grep`:

```
--line-buffered
    Force output to be line buffered.  By default, output is line buffered when standard
    output is a terminal and block buffered otherwise.
```

Answer (score 3):

The output of the `grep` in the middle is not a terminal, so it is using block buffering instead of line buffering. You have to force line buffering using `--line-buffered` option.

```
tail -f eclipse.log | grep --line-buffered 'enimation' | grep  -i 'tap'
```

In case of other commands, which don't provide such an option, you can use `stdbuf` command to force line buffering, e.g.:

```
tail -f eclipse.log | stdbuf -o1 grep 'enimation' | grep  -i 'tap'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output is getting buffered. Try:

```
tail -f eclipse.log | grep --line-buffered 'enimation' | grep --line-buffered -i 'tap'
```

Comment: Ups, I see I'm not first here

Answer (score -2):

Try adding the `-E` option to `grep`. A lot of reflex features don't work without it. I usually refer to it as the "yes, I **do** know what I'm doing" option.

Comment: -1 Complete red herring.  There are no extended regular expression features in the question.

Comment: `-E` option is the short form of `--extended-regexp`. From man: `Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression`. In this case, PATTERN is 'enimation' and it doesn't change whether is interpreted as a *extended-regexp*

Comment: The -E option might help if we want to filter by both patterns enimation **and** tap but not if we want to filter _first_ enimation _then_ tap if tap is anywhere in the line... a proper way to achieve the first case is `tail -f eclipse.log | grep -iE "enimation|tap"` or `tail -f eclipse.log | grep -iE "enimation.*tap"` if we are sure about the sequence (tap always being after enimation), all this to prevent performance issues about --line-buffered option.