# In C, what's the size of stdout buffer?

Tags: c, linux, unix

Today I learned that stdout is line buffered when it's set to terminal and buffered in different cases. So, in normal situation, if I use printf() without the terminating '\n' it will be printed on the screen only when the buffer will be full. How to get a size of this buffer, how big is this?

Comment: If you don't want the buffering, why not use one of the other standard library functions that doesn't require it?  Or perhaps you could just include the `\n` terminator.

Comment: I just don't know what's the size of the stdout buffer. I know what you said, I just want to know how much data must be collected for buffer to be regarded full and the text printed on the screen

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The actual size is defined by the individual implementation; the standard doesn't mandate a minimum size (based on what I've been able to find, anyway).  Don't have a clue on how you'd determine the size of the buffer.

**Edit**

[Chapter and verse](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> #### 7.19.3 Files
>
> ...
> 3 When a stream is *unbuffered*, characters are intended to appear from the source or at the
> destination as soon as possible. Otherwise characters may be accumulated and
> transmitted to or from the host environment as a block. When a stream is *fully buffered*,
> characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when
> a buffer is ﬁlled. When a stream is *line buffered*, characters are intended to be
> transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line character is
> encountered. Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host
> environment when a buffer is ﬁlled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or
> when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of
> characters from the host environment. **Support for these characteristics is
> implementation-deﬁned, and may be affected via the `setbuf` and `setvbuf` functions**.

Emphasis added.

"Implementation-defined" is not a euphemism for "I don't know", it's simply a statement that the language standard explicitly leaves it up to the *implementation* to *define* the behavior.

And having said that, there *is* a non-programmatic way to find out; consult the documentation for your compiler.  "Implementation-defined" also means that the implementation *must* document the behavior:

> #### 3.4.1
>
> 1 **implementation-deﬁned behavior**
> unspeciﬁed behavior where each implementation documents how the choice is made
> 2 EXAMPLE An example of implementation-deﬁned behavior is the propagation of the high-order bit
> when a signed integer is shifted right.

Comment: I hear 'it depends on the implementation' so often that I start to think that sometimes it's just the way to say 'I don't know', but you have said that clearly, so ok ;p

Comment: "it depends on the implementation" means the implementer can implement it as they see fit and still compliant to the standard. if you really want to know how big that buffer is, you can keep writing into it without any "\n" til it overflows.

Comment: How can I see if buffer overflows, finally there will be no characters printed and it will start from 1 again?

Comment: you can print the count of the character to stderr (which is unbuffered) and see when the first buffered characters comes out, I leave the implementation as homework for you.

Comment: I wrote this http://pastebin.com/DjMnbCvy and it seems that the size of the buffer is 1024 on my x64 Slackware.

Comment: @John Bode: thank you for this information, I didn't want to be offensive. I have found a confirmation that buffer size is 1024 here http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/, but on this page it says 'if stdin/stdout are connected to a terminal', what does it mean?

Comment: @user1042840: `stdin` and `stdout` can be redirected to point to a file or different device where the buffering strategy may be different.

Comment: This actually depends on the libc which you are using, not the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

The Linux when a pipe is created for default pipe size 64K is used.
In /proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size the maximum pipe size exists.
For the default 1048576 is typical.

For glibc's default file buffer; 65536 bytes seems reasonable.
However, ascertained by grep from the glibc source tree:
libio/libio.h:#define _IO_BUFSIZ _G_BUFSIZ
sysdeps/generic/_G_config.h:#define _G_BUFSIZ 8192
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/_G_config.h:#define _G_BUFSIZ 8192

By that the original question might or might not be answered.
For a minute's effort the best guess is 8 kilobytes.

For mere line buffering 8K is adequate.
However, for more than line buffered output
as compared with 64K; 8K is not efficient.
Because for the default pipe size 64K is used and
if a larger pipe size is not expected and
if a larger pipe size is not explicitly set
then for a stdio buffer 64K is recommended.

If performance is required
then meager 8K buffers do not suffice.
By fcntl(pipefd,F_SETPIPE_SZ,1048576)
a pipe's size can be increased.
By setvbuf (stdout,buffer,_IOFBF,1048576)
a stdio provided file buffer can be replaced.
If a pipe is not used
then pipe size is irrelevant.
However, if between two processes data is piped
then by increasing pipe size a performance boon could become.
Otherwise
by the smallest buffer or
by the smallest pipe
a bottleneck is created.

If reading also
then by a larger buffer
by stdio fewer read function invocations might be required.
By the word "might" an important consideration is suggested.
As by provided
by a single write function invocation
by a single read  function invocation
as much data can be read.
By a read function invocation
a return with fewer bytes than requested can be expected.
By an additional read function invocation
additional bytes may be gained.

For writing a data line; by stdio overkill is provided.
However, by stdio line buffered output is possible.
In some scenarios line buffered output is essential.
If writing to a proc virtual file system provided file or
if writing to a sys  virtual file system provided file
then in a single write buffer
the line feed byte should be included.
If a second write is used
then an unexpected outcome could become.

If read write and stdio are mixed
then caveats exist.
Before
a write  function invocation
a fflush function invocation is required.
Because stderr is not buffered;
for stderr the fflush function invocation is not required.
By read fewer than expected bytes might be provided.
By stdio the previous bytes might already be buffered.

Not mixing unistd and stdio I/O is good advise, but often ignored.
Mixing   buffered input  is unreasonable.
Mixing unbuffered input  is possible.
Mixing   buffered output is plausible.

By  stdio buffered IO convenience is provided.
Without stdio buffered IO is possible.
However, for the code additional bytes are required.
When a sufficient sized buffer is leveraged;
compared with stdio provided output functions;
the write function invocation is not necessarily slower.

However, when a pipe is not involved
then by function mmap superior IO can be provided.
On a pipe by mmap an error is not returned.
However, in the address space the data is not provided.
On a pipe by lseek an error is provided.

Lastly by man 3 setvbuf a good example is provided.
If on the stack the buffer is allocated
then before a return a fclose function invocation
must not be omitted.

The actual question was 
"In C, what's the size of stdout buffer?"
By 8192 that much might be answered.

By those who encounter this inquiry
curiosity concerning buffer input/output efficiency might exist.
By some inquiries the goal is implicitly approached.
By a preference for terse replies
the pipe   size significance and
the buffer size significance and
mmap is not explicated.
This reply explicates.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer) are some pretty interesting answers on a similar question.

on a linux system you can view buffer sizes from different functions, including `ulimit`. 
Also the header files `limits.h` and `pipe.h` should contain that kind of info.

Answer (score -3):

You could set it to unbuffered, or just flush it.

This seems to have some decent info when the C runtime typically flushes it for you and some examples. Take a look at [this](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/98138-fflush-stdout.html).

Comment: Thx, but what I would like to know is know how much data must be collected for buffer to be regarded full and the text printed on the screen in Linux or other *nik systems? What's the size of the fictional BUFFER, so often mentioned.