# Can writing to Tensorboard cause memory (RAM) OOM issues? (especially in PyTorch)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am running pytorch code that logs to tensorboard summary writers. But I am also getting memory issues (my jobs are being SIGKILLed). I am trying to figure out why. I am thus curious if it is the part of my code the writes to a tensorboard file? I am also doing other things like caching tensors which might be the source of the issue but I want to isolate **this** question to one single this:

> **Does tensorboard write to disk when logging each iteration?** (or some other way tensorboard might cause a memory issue e.g. doing `tb.add_scalar(tag1, loss, it)` or does it keep everything in memory first and that's why maybe my memory error is occurring?

error messages:

From condor HPC:

```
000 (6466.000.000) 05/03 17:20:00 Job submitted from host: <130.126.112.32:9618?addrs=130.126.112.32-9618+[--1]-9618&noUDP&sock=1423_a35b_4>
...
001 (6466.000.000) 05/03 18:34:52 Job executing on host: <172.22.224.113:9618?addrs=172.22.224.113-9618+[--1]-9618&noUDP&sock=2060_912f_3>
...
006 (6466.000.000) 05/03 18:35:00 Image size of job updated: 13872
10 - MemoryUsage of job (MB)
9564 - ResidentSetSize of job (KB)
...
006 (6466.000.000) 05/03 18:40:00 Image size of job updated: 53368188
51096 - MemoryUsage of job (MB)
52322148 - ResidentSetSize of job (KB)
...
006 (6466.000.000) 05/03 18:45:01 Image size of job updated: 86845436
83789 - MemoryUsage of job (MB)
85799388 - ResidentSetSize of job (KB)
...
006 (6466.000.000) 05/03 18:50:02 Image size of job updated: 120496460
116651 - MemoryUsage of job (MB)
119450412 - ResidentSetSize of job (KB)
...
006 (6466.000.000) 05/03 18:55:02 Image size of job updated: 129339104
123232 - MemoryUsage of job (MB)
126189336 - ResidentSetSize of job (KB)
...
005 (6466.000.000) 05/03 18:56:10 Job terminated.
(1) Normal termination (return value 0)
Usr 0 00:57:39, Sys 0 00:04:24 - Run Remote Usage
Usr 0 00:00:00, Sys 0 00:00:00 - Run Local Usage
Usr 0 00:57:39, Sys 0 00:04:24 - Total Remote Usage
Usr 0 00:00:00, Sys 0 00:00:00 - Total Local Usage
0 - Run Bytes Sent By Job
0 - Run Bytes Received By Job
0 - Total Bytes Sent By Job
0 - Total Bytes Received By Job
Partitionable Resources : Usage Request Allocated
Cpus : 8 8
Disk (KB) : 2 2 1252638
Gpus : 4 4
Memory (MB) : 123232 1 1
...
```

from my code:

```
I get the following error:

Starting training...

n_epoch=0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/miranda9/ML4Coq/ml4coq-proj-src/embeddings_zoo/tree_nns/main_brando.py", line 282, in <module>
main_distributed()
File "/home/miranda9/ML4Coq/ml4coq-proj-src/embeddings_zoo/tree_nns/main_brando.py", line 193, in main_distributed
mp.spawn(fn=train, args=(opts,), nprocs=opts.world_size)
File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/coq-tactician-graph/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 199, in spawn
return start_processes(fn, args, nprocs, join, daemon, start_method='spawn')
File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/coq-tactician-graph/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 157, in start_processes
while not context.join():
File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/coq-tactician-graph/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 105, in join
raise Exception(
Exception: process 1 terminated with signal SIGKILL
JOB ENDED
```

---

edit:

Training code as requested by the commentator:

```
    def train(self, n_epoch):
        self.tactic_predictor.train()
        avg_loss = AverageMeter('train loss')
        avg_acc = AverageMeter('train accuracy')

        bar = ProgressBar(max_value=len(self.dataloaders['train']))
        self.log(f"{len(self.dataloaders['train'].dataset)=}")
        self.log(f"{len(self.dataloaders['train'])=}")
        self.log(f"{len(self.dataloaders['train'].dataset)//self.opts.batch_size=}")
        self.log(f"{len(self.dataloaders['train'])*self.opts.world_size=}")
        for i, data_batch in enumerate(self.dataloaders['train']):
            # self.log(f'--- {i=}')
            # self.log(f'{data_batch[0][0].f}')
            data_batch = process_batch_ddp_tactic_prediction(self.opts, data_batch)
            # self.log(f'{type(data_batch)=}')
            loss, logits = self.tactic_predictor(data_batch)
            # self.log(f'{loss=}')
            acc = accuracy(output=logits, target=data_batch['tac_label'])
            avg_loss.update(loss.item(), self.opts.batch_size)
            avg_acc.update(acc.item(), self.opts.batch_size)

            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            # self.log(f'done optimizer.zero_grad()')
            loss.backward()  # each process synchronizes it's gradients in the backward pass
            # self.log(f'done loss.backward()')
            self.optimizer.step()  # the right update is done since all procs have the right synced grads
            # self.log(f'done optimizer.step()')

            if self.is_lead_worker() and i % 10 == 0:
                bar.update(i) if self.is_lead_worker() else None
                val_loss, val_acc = self.valid(n_epoch, val_iterations=1)
                self.log_tb(it=i, tag1='train loss', loss=loss.item(), tag2='train acc', acc=acc.item())
                self.log_tb(it=i, tag1='val loss', loss=val_loss.item(), tag2='val acc', acc=val_acc.item())

                self.log(f"\n{i=}: {loss=} {acc=}")
                self.log(f"{i=}: {val_loss=} {val_acc=}")

            gc.collect()
            # self.log(f'just did gc.collect()')

        return avg_loss.item(), avg_acc.item()
```

Comment: Please provide the code (at least training loop) that you used. I don't think there is any evidence that tensorboard is the issue from the error.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/766).

Comment: @M.Innat that is a long thread! Is there a summary of it what is going on? (though thanks for the reference! :) )

Comment: Shortly, you can upgrade the tensorboard to the latest version.  However, if you're using tensorboardX, I'm not sure about it, you can ask the concern tensorboardX GitHub. Also, it would be better if you could possibly provide some reproducible code.