# Linux stdout where writes the log and how much memory assigned to it

Tags: linux, stdout, filebeat

I am using `ConsoleAppender` for logging in my Java application.
`ConsoleAppender` writes to the `System.out` which is `stdout` in case of Linux.

Can someone help me understanding where does `stdout` logs go and how much is the memory assigned to it.

I need to know this because all my logs to `stdout` are not being picked by filebeat to put in the elastic search index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone help me understanding where does stdout logs go

Usually `stdout` simply goes into the buffer of your shell which is usually not buffered/recorded to any file. I say *usually* because I am sure that there are some special systems & Linux distributions that can handle things differently.
For the rest, I assume that you use a "common Linux desktop or server distribution."

However, what you can do is **redirecting** `stdout` to a file.

I assume that you launch your application similar to this:

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

Your application outputs to `stdout` which allows you to see the output in the terminal.

On Linux (I'd say most Unix systems), you can simply redirect the `stdout` (and optionally `stderr`) to a file like this:

```
java -jar myapp.jar > output.txt
```

A file named `output.txt` should then be created on your system.
If you still need "real time user feedback" you can simply do something like

```
tail -f output.txt
```

to continiously print the contents of `output.txt` to `stdout`.

> how much is the memory assigned to it.

Your `output.txt` file will grow until you run out of disk space. You can use your distributions log rotation system to limit the size of the file. FreeBSD uses [newlogsys(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?newsyslog). I am sure that the Linux distribution of your choice comes with a similar system already in place.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414496/joel-bodenmann in the first case where redirection of application log is not happening, it will go to buffer, can you tell me what is the size of that buffer.

Comment: This is depending on the implementation. You might find this question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904067/in-c-whats-the-size-of-stdout-buffer

Comment: Furthermore, if your system design relies on knowing this information then you should most likely consider changing your design. Something as simple as an `stdout` redirection to a file as described in my answer is not only very easy to do, but also intended use of the underlying operating system and the other involved components.