# how many bytes are reserved for stdin, std_out, stdderror, stdprt, and stdaux?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, kernel, nasm

how many bytes are reserved for stdin, std_out, stdderror, stdprt, and stdaux?
every pc seems to describe the std streams as set up by the os, yet i'm trying to build my own os, and that means making my own std streams,
I'D LIKE DETAILS FOR CONSOLE, FILE AND NETWORK
its because i'm using masm and need to give it at least an initial storage size

Comment: You likely want a position, some way to identify the the backing file and maybe a buffer.

Comment: It will vary, depending on what kind device the streams are bound to, whether interactive console, file, or network.

Comment: Do you mean size of buffer for block-buffering `stdio`? By defauls it is `BUFSZ`, likely defined as 8192 bytes.

Comment: IF you mean how big a stream buffer should be then, you can pick up any size. Including zero. The output streams write to their respective devices, if a program attempt to write while a write is still in progress the call blocks. If the user types too fast the key is lost (pretty much like what happens in DOS when a program freezes but the BIOS can still accept input from the keyboard). Buffers decouple the writer side from the reader side. The exact size is kind of eye-balled. I'd make it 4KiB to start with.

Comment: "I'D LIKE DETAILS FOR CONSOLE, FILE AND NETWORK" - **Single problem** for a question post, please. Also make sure you have searched enough before the asking a question. E.g. size of the buffer for stdin is described in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904067/in-c-whats-the-size-of-stdout-buffer).

Comment: this is a a single question

Comment: Not that it matters for the choice of buffer sizes, but you tagged this [nasm] but said in the question you're using MASM.

Answer (score -1):

i'm going to use 1048576 bits, i'll adjust this answer if its wrong

Comment: Plz provide a real answer, not a guess, or just leave a comment.