# printf jokes in multi-threaded application?

Tags: c, pthreads, printf

How can the following code

```
while(1) {
  client_name_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_name, &client_name_len);
  if (newsockfd < 0) {
    perror("ERROR on accept");
    printf("Finished\n");
    close(sockfd);
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("a:");
  pthread_t thread1;
  int *addr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  *addr = newsockfd;
  pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &ProcessClient, (void*)addr);
}
```

produce the following output:

```
a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:ERROR on accept: Too many open files
a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:a:Finished
```

The problem is that `perror("ERROR on accept")`, `printf("Finished\n")` and `printf("a:")` are executed in the same thread, but the output is mixed.

ProcessClient does not output anything and does not create any threads.
`sockfd` is a standard listening tcp socket.

Comment: What is the joke?  Either it was written by Fonzie or a Canadian. :-)

Comment: I am assuming the OP meant “chokes”. But the question is funnier with “jokes”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `printf("a:");` and `printf("Finished\n");` are buffered I/O going to stdout.

`perror("ERROR on accept");` is unbuffered (or immediately flushed) I/O going to stderr.

So the many `a:`'s that show up after the `ERROR on accept: Too many open files` were actually `printf()`'ed before, but buffering makes them show up later on the console.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3746795/12711 for details and methods to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael pointed out, the first problem is that you're using two different streams (stdout and stderr), and that one is buffered while the other is unbuffered. However, you're also breaking the output up into multiple stdio calls, which makes it non-atomic. I would forst recommend either replacing the `perror` with:

```
printf("ERROR on accept: %s\n", strerror_l(errno));
```

or switching the other `printf` calls to use `fprintf` on `stderr`, so that you're consistent about which stream you're writing to.

Then, to make it atomic, call `flockfile(f)` at the beginning of your function and `funlockfile(f)` before you return (where `f` is replaced by whichever of `stdout` or `stderr` you choose to use). Or if you really still want to use both, you could lock both of them...