# Difference between puts() and printf() in C while using sleep()

Tags: c, sleep, puts

I was wondering the difference between puts() and printf() functions while using sleep() function.

Here is my code(In C language):

```
printf("hello, world");
sleep(1);
printf("Good, bye!");
```

After compiling and running the program, it seems that it will **sleep first** and then print "hello, worldGood, bye!"

However, if using puts() instead of printf(), it will print "hello, world" then sleep, and finally print "Good, bye".

```
puts("hello, world");
sleep(1);
puts("Good, bye!);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because of buffering - by default, standard out buffers up to each new line. `printf()` does not include a newline, so output isn't flushed. `puts()` includes a newline, so output is flushed.

You can cause `printf()` to flush by putting a newline:

```
printf("hello, world\n");
```

or by calling `fflush()` directly:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

For more about buffering, see the man page for [`setbuf()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/setbuf.3.html):

> ```
> The three types of buffering available are unbuffered, block buffered, and
>    line buffered.  When an output stream is unbuffered, information appears on
>    the destination file or terminal as soon as written; when it is block 
>    buffered many characters are saved up and written as a block; when it 
>    is line buffered characters are saved up until a newline is output or input
>    is read from any stream attached to a terminal device (typically stdin).
>    ....
>    If a stream refers to a terminal (as stdout normally does) it is 
>    line buffered. 
>    ....
>    The standard error stream stderr is always unbuffered by default.
> ```

Answer (score 9):

It's because `puts` is also outputting a newline character which, on devices that can be determined to be interactive, causes flushing by default (for standard output) <sup>(a)</sup>.

You should see a similar effect if your initial `printf` outputs a newline at the end:

```
printf("hello, world\n");
```

or if you `fflush (stdout);` before the `sleep()` call.

The relevant part of `C11` is `7.21.3 Files`, section `/7`:

> At program startup, three text streams are predefined and need not be opened explicitly
>   — standard input (for reading conventional input), standard output (for writing
>   conventional output), and standard error (for writing diagnostic output). As initially
>   opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard
>   output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer
>   to an interactive device.

This harks back to the days of `C89/90 4.9.3 Files`:

> At program startup, three text streams are predefined and need not be opened explicitly --- standard input (for reading conventional input), standard output (for writing conventional output), and standard error (for writing diagnostic output).  When opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.

---

<sup>(a)</sup>: It's not *quite* that simple. For starters, this is implementation dependent simply because the standard states that what constitutes an interactive device is implementation dependent (the *behaviour* is specified but not the thing that affects that behaviour).

Secondly (as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723795/is-stdout-line-buffered-unbuffered-or-indeterminate-by-default)), the standard only mandates when standard output becomes *fully* bufferd (when the device is definitely not interactive). Whether it's unbuffered or line buffered for interactive devices is an implementation decision.

Comment: Solid answer. If you mention that the standard has been this way since C89, I'll give you the +1 that'll put you above my answer :)

Comment: Far be it for me to pass up some cheap rep. I just happen to have c90 lying around on the hard disk. Now I can go home and tell the wife my "never throw anything out" strategy has benefits - she _won't_ be happy about that :-)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, printf will flush the stream if a newline `\n` is present.
puts, I'm not really sure.  It may be implementation dependant.

Your sleep is just long enough for printf which is not containing a `\n` to flush the stream.

I recommend you flush the stream when required with `fflush(stdout);`  Then you can avoid the sleep altogether.