# Output from subprocess is not available on unbuffered stdout pipe before the subprocess terminates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I've created a subprocess using `subprocess.Popen(['myapp'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, bufsize=0)` that executes a C-program that writes to `stdout` using e.g. `puts()`.

The problem is that the Python program blocks in `p.stdout.read(1024)`, although the subprocess starts by `puts("HelloWorld")`. Only after the subprocess terminates, is output available on `p.stdout`. I thought that `bufsize=0` would mean that pipes become unbuffered, so that output is immediately available on the pipe.

I have read the below question, which states that newlines should cause output to be flushed. However, `puts()` prints a newline, so are the pipes not recognized as an interactive device?

[Difference between puts() and printf() in C while using sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680252/difference-between-puts-and-printf-in-c-while-using-sleep)

> It's because puts is also outputting a newline character which, on
>   devices that can be determined to be interactive, causes flushing by
>   default (for standard output) (a).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried flushing after each `puts` from the C program?

Answer (score 0):

This is *application* behavior. Even if the *pipe* is unbuffered, applications normally buffer information that they are going to write to a file *(any type of file)* for some time before actually writing it.  As Jon's comment above indicates, a system-call like `fflush()` can be used by programs to ensure that they actually have posted the data, and, if applicable, that a physical I/O operation has actually completed.

Comment: Thank you. But why does the C-program works as expected, when it is executed from the shell? Here, everything gets output as it should, i.e. puts() appears before scanf() etc. I don't understand why I don't see this behavior with pipes.