# Please help in finding the error in my program

Tags: c

I know the program I am posting is very basic but I am unable to find the error. I rechecked everything but despite no compilation error, the output is not coming.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    while(1)
    {
        if((scanf("%d",&i))!=42)
        {
            printf("%d",i);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Thank You for your time and consideration.

Comment: Ugh - please indent your code correctly.

Comment: Is the problem that the code runs in an infinite loop?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: 1. No proper formatting, 2. No error description, 3. No input, 4. No expected output.

Comment: @NishithJainMR Indentation is OK, but please *do not* modify the actual code.

Comment: Guys first of all thanks a lot for your help. I got the answer.
I am really sorry that I made a few mistakes while posting. Actually I am new here so I didn't notice the correct way of posting. In future I will take care of all this when posting questions.

Thanks a lot

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Sorry brother... I manually started indenting the code. Sorry again...

Comment: @NishithJainMR No problem, it was just a very curious edit (the added space in the `scanf` format string) that *could* have impacted the meaning of the question.

Comment: :-) Yes I know, even I didn't notice that I added a space in there...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`scanf`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/) does not return the value entered. It returns the *number of inputs matched*. So your check for 42 is incorrect.  It will return 1 if an integer was assigned to `i`, or 0 if there was invalid input. If you want to exit the loop when the user enters 42, you should explicitly test `if (i == 42)`.

As [simonc mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677313/please-help-in-finding-the-error-in-my-program#comment30963003_20677347), The reason you're not getting any output is because `printf("%d",i);` is not printing a newline `"\n"` after the number, and the standard out (`stdout`) stream [is *line-buffered*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723795/is-stdout-line-buffered-unbuffered-or-indeterminate-by-default). That means the standard library is going to continue to buffer up your `printf`s until a newline is encountered. At this point the buffer will be *flushed* to the console.

The solution is to add the newline (which is probably what you desire anyway): `printf("%d\n",i);`  Alternatively, you could call `fflush(stdout)` to tell the std library to flush the buffered content to the console immediately.  Or, writing to `stderr` will output immediately, because it is *unbuffered*.

---

This should demonstrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    while(1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Enter a number (or 42 to quit): ");
        if((scanf("%d",&i)) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
            continue;
        }
        if (i==42)
            break;

        printf("Number provided: %d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.exe
Enter a number (or 42 to quit): 17
Number provided: 17
Enter a number (or 42 to quit): 42
$
```

Comment: I think the question is asking why nothing is printed to stdout ("the output is not coming").  Isn't this because of the lack of a newline in the format string passed to `printf` (and/or lack of `fflish(stdout)`?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the `scanf` function's return value to `42`, not the variable `i's` value.
maybe you should read this
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf

Comment: Your grammar is incredibly misleading. It should say "You *are comparing* `scanf` ... to 42", and that "You *should be comparing* ... to 1"

Comment: @JonathonReinhart  fix ok.