# When pty [Pseudo terminal] slave fd settings are changed by "tcsetattr" , how can the master end capture this event without delay?

Tags: linux, ioctl, pty

The slave fd is used by another application (say "A") as a serial port device .

A will set its baud rate/stop bit etc. My app needs this information .

BTW, is there any way for a process that has only the master fd open to be notified of all `ioctl()` calls that are issued to the slave fd ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is possible (in Linux and pre-2004 FreeBSD) , using the pty in packet mode and setting the EXTPROC flag on it.

- Packet mode is enabled on the master end by `ioctl(master, TIOCPKT, &nonzero)`. Now every `read` on the master end will yield a *packet*: whatever was written on the other side, plus a status byte that says something about the situation on the slave end ("The write queue for the terminal (i.e. the slave end)  is flushed")
- This doesn't mean, however, that the master is *immediately* aware of changes on the slave end, e.g. a `select()` on the master will *not* return as soon as those changes happen, only when there is something to read
- However, after setting EXTPROC in the pty's local flag word - using `tcsetattr()` - `select()` *will* return as soon as the slave state changes, and one can then inspect the slaves termios - either directly via the slave fd which we keep open in the parent process, or, on linux at least, simply by `tcgetattr()` on the master side.
- Note that EXTPROC disables certain parts of the pty driver, e.g. local echoing is turned off.

EXTPROC is not used a lot ([here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-readline/2011-01/msg00004.html) is a possible use case), not very portable and not documented at all (it shoud at least have been somewhere in the linux `termios` or `tty_ioctl` manpages). Looking at the linux kernel source `drivers/tty/n_tty.c` I conclude that any change in the slaves termios structure will make the `select()` on the master end return - but a `tcsetattr()` that doesn't change anything won't.

Edit: in response to J.F. Sebastians's request below I give an example program that should make clear how to use `EXTRPOC` in packet mode on a linux machine:

```c
/* Demo program for managing a pty in packet mode with the slave's
** EXTPROC bit set, where the master gets notified of changes in the
** slaves terminal attributes
**   
** save as extproc.c, compile with gcc -o extproc extproc.c -lutil
*/



#include <stdio.h>
#include <pty.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFSIZE 512

void main() {
  int master;      // fd of master side
  pid_t pid;
  if((pid = forkpty(&master, NULL, NULL, NULL))) { // we're parent
    fd_set rfds, xfds;
    int retval, nread, status = 0, nonzero = 1;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];

    ioctl(master, TIOCPKT, &nonzero); // initiate packet mode - necessary to get notified of
                                      // ioctl() on the slave side
    while(1) {
      // set stdout unbuffered (we want to see stuff as it happens)                                                                                 
      setbuf(stdout, NULL);

      // prepare the file descriptor sets
      FD_ZERO(&rfds);
      FD_SET(master, &rfds);

      FD_ZERO(&xfds);
      FD_SET(master, &xfds);

      // now wait until status of master changes     
      printf("---- waiting for something to happen -----\n");
      select(1 + master, &rfds, NULL, &xfds, NULL);

      char *r_text = (FD_ISSET(master, &rfds) ? "master ready for reading" : "- ");
      char *x_text = (FD_ISSET(master, &xfds) ? "exception on master" : "- ");

      printf("rfds: %s, xfds: %s\n", r_text, x_text);
      if ((nread = read(master, buf, BUFSIZE-1)) < 0) 
        perror("read error");
      else {         
        buf[nread] = '\0';
        // In packet mode *buf will be the status byte , and buf + 1 the "payload"
        char *pkt_txt = (*buf &  TIOCPKT_IOCTL ? " (TIOCPKT_IOCTL)" : "");
        printf("read %d bytes: status byte %x%s, payload <%s>\n", nread, *buf, pkt_txt, buf + 1);
      }
      if (waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG) && WIFEXITED(status)) {
        printf("child exited with status %x\n", status);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      } 
    }
  } else { // child
    struct termios tio;

    // First set the EXTPROC bit in the slave end termios structure
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &tio);
    tio.c_lflag |= EXTPROC;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tio); 

    // Wait a bit and do an ordinary write()
    sleep(1);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,"blah", 4);

    // Wait a bit and change the pty terminal attributes. This will be picked up by the master end
    sleep(1);
    tio.c_cc[VINTR] = 0x07; 
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tio);

    // Wait a bit and exit
    sleep(1);
  } 
}
```

The output will be something like:

```
---- waiting for something to happen -----
rfds: master ready for reading, xfds: exception on master
read 1 bytes: status byte 40 (TIOCPKT_IOCTL), payload <>
---- waiting for something to happen -----
rfds: master ready for reading, xfds: - 
read 5 bytes: status byte 0, payload <blah>
---- waiting for something to happen -----
rfds: master ready for reading, xfds: exception on master
read 1 bytes: status byte 40 (TIOCPKT_IOCTL), payload <>
---- waiting for something to happen -----
rfds: master ready for reading, xfds: - 
read error: Input/output error
child exited with status 0
```

In general, the master end of a pty need not be a tty (and have an associated `termios` structure), but under Linux, it is (with a shared `termios`: changes on one end will change both `termios` structures at the same time).

This means that we can modify the example program above and set `EXTPROC` on the master side, it won't make any difference.

All of this is not documented as far as I can see, and even less portable, of course.

Comment: Could you provide some reference for the statements in the answer? How did you find out about TIOCPKT, EXTPROC, select() behavior with a pty?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I modified my answer above by including an example program. I dont't remember how I found out about `TIOCPKT` and `EXTPROC`: they are hardly mentioned on the Web (and apparently not much used nowadays)

Comment: 1- I've got `read error` line first (due to stdout buffering. Disabling it (`setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);`) produces expected output) 2- [setting EXTPROC only in the parent doesn't produce notifications on my Linux machine](https://gist.github.com/zed/71bc51d8968dc04f44076596ec5f73ef)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: **1** By default, stdout [should be line buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723795/is-stdout-line-buffered-unbuffered-or-indeterminate-by-default) in linux. I added `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` just to be certain. **2** I think you made a mistake there: you set `EXTPROC` on `stdin` instead of `master`

Comment: 1- If stdout is a pipe; [it may be fully buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279). For some reason a compilation buffer in emacs used a pipe instead of a pty in this case. It is my mistake that I didn't notice it and didn't check in a terminal. 2- The "stdin instead of master" is even more embarrassing. I've fixed it and it works as described in the answer. I should have gone to bed 8 hours ago. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Don't worry: I'm glad you took the time to check it all, and that I'm not the only one making such mistakes...

Comment: With packet mode, is the additional byte at start only in master end (not in slave) ? Thanks,

Comment: @ransh: You are right. As the manpage for [ioctl_tty](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_tty.2.html) states: _Can be applied to the master side of a pseudoterminal only_. It would wreak havoc if the `ioctl()` on the master side would make the slave end read en extra byte for each `read()`, so the effect of the `ioctl()` is _only_ visible at the master end

Comment: @Hans: Thanks, one more if I may. I see on above answer that  EXTPROC is configured for slave stdin, but isn't it supposed to be configured for master fd ? (as you wrote in one of the comments above)

Comment: No, `TIOCPKT` has to be set on the master, but `EXTPROC`  _should_ be configured on the slave end like in the example code above. I only observed that on a linux machine, master and slave appear to share their `termios` structure (at least back then) so that the EXTPROC can be set on the master side as well. All this is undocumented and not portable, in other words: not recommended!