# Does terminal control function setting baud rate really effective for pseudo terminals?

Tags: linux, terminal, rate, pty

> I know:

Nowadays, when we logon linux, either desktop or by ssh remote, the linux system allocates a pseudo terminal under /dev/pty for us, right?

> My question:

So some unix functions which is used to set baud rate: seems they're for real physical devices, are they still effective for pseudo terminals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The baud rate setting for a pseudo-terminal doesn't *control* anything, but advises the terminal driver (when it matters) how to synchronize with a physical device, as well as advising applications if they should send padding characters.

A pseudo-terminal might be connected to a physical device, but there's no way for an application to tell the difference.  Physical devices are still used (perhaps not by you).

For example, [xterm has an option](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_327), used for testing ncurses:

> *Patch #327 - 2016/10/07*
>   add **`-baudrate`** option, for testing ncurses.

but you would not find it useful.

Comment: according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641754/when-pty-pseudo-terminal-slave-fd-settings-are-changed-by-tcsetattr-how-ca seems that the answer is wrong.

Comment: It's not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The baud rate is ignored for pseudo terminals. It is possible to set any baud rate the driver remembers it but it does not use it for any action:

```
# stty speed
38400
# stty speed 1200
# stty speed
1200
```

It looks the speed is set but it has no effect to pseudo terminal driver. It has effect only if the terminal driver is connected to UART.