# Python sys.stderr flush frequency

Tags: python, buffer, flush, stderr

How often does sys.stderr flush its buffer, and is this standard among different environments?

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.__stderr__
<open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x2b4fcb7ac270>
```

I see that it is just a standard file type, but I don't know what value of [*buffering*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) it's supposed to be. `dir()` does not seem to yield any useful information either.

Comment: stderr, independent of `sys.stderr`, is usually unbuffered.

Comment: Just came across a use case where stderr is buffered and it causes problems:

`docker run -d -p 8000:8000 ubuntu python3 -m http.server` runs a python HTTP server daemon. All output is to stderr and python will not flush it to `docker logs` without the `-u` flag given in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**: `sys.stderr` is line-buffered by default since Python 3.9. If `python` receives `-u` command-line option or `$PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable is set, then stdout and stderr streams are forced to be unbuffered (including text layer since Python 3.7).

---

<sup>old answer:</sup>

On Python 2, I can't find where in the documentation `sys.stderr`'s buffering is specified. I'd expect the same behaviour as  [`stderr` in C that is unbuffered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3746795/4279) [(except Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c565h7xx.aspx) and I don't know whether c99 standard mandates it. [The standard error stream is not fully buffered](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html) in POSIX. [`-u` option forces standard streams to be unbuffered](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) in Python 2.

[On Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stderr):

> When interactive, standard streams are line-buffered. Otherwise, they
> are block-buffered like regular text files. You can override this
> value with the `-u` command-line option.

[`-u` command-line option](http://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u):

> Force the binary layer of the stdout and stderr streams (which is
> available as their `buffer` attribute) to be unbuffered. The text I/O
> layer will still be line-buffered if writing to the console, or
> block-buffered if redirected to a non-interactive file.

Comment: Important change:
Changed in version 3.7: The text layer of the stdout and stderr streams now is unbuffered.