# Is there equivalent of clog in C?

Tags: c

I know this is true for C++:

```
         buffering  output

cerr:    unbuffered stderr
clog:    buffered   stderr
cout:    buffered   stdout
```

In C equivalents for `cerr` and `cout` are:

```
cerr:    fprintf(stderr, ...)
cout:    fprintf(stdout, ...) or printf(...)
```

Is there an equivalent for `clog`?

Comment: `cout` is buffered, but see "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723795/is-stdout-line-buffered-unbuffered-or-indeterminate-by-default " as buffering doesn't work exactly the same in C and C++. I'm not sure that adding a buffer to `stderr` is a good idea, since then you have to remember to `fflush` it when writing actual errors, or fatal ones won't make it out.

Comment: @Potatoswatter thanks, I changed cout to buffered. I would never use clog for actual errors, so it's not a problem if it's not flushed.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. C++ `clog` and `cout` are always buffered, but the question is about C `stderr`. If you change it to buffered, then you have no unbuffered error output facility in C.

Comment: @Potatoswatter You are right, I was thinking about C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, C has only `stderr` and `stdout` and standard output streams. But you can set the buffering on `stderr` as you please with `setvbuf`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using `setvbuf` and full buffering (`_IOFBF`):

> Full buffering: On output, data is written once the buffer is full (or
>   flushed). On Input, the buffer is filled when an input operation is
>   requested and the buffer is empty.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buff[BUFSIZ];

    setvbuf(stderr, buff, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ);
    fprintf(stderr, "Hello world\n");
    getchar();
    fflush(stderr);
    return 0;
}
```

> The value of BUFSIZ is chosen on each system so as to make stream I/O
>   efficient. So it is a good idea to use BUFSIZ as the size for the
>   buffer when you call setvbuf.