# Time Complexity of a printf()?

Tags: c, time, printf, big-o, complexity-theory

I'd like to determine time complexity of a printf such as:

```
{
    printf("%d",
           i);
}
```

Or:

```
{
    printf("%c",
           array[i]);
}
```

Is it correct to assume that time complexity of a printf is always O(1) or not?

[EDIT] Let's take a function that swaps two values:

```
void swap(...)

{

      tmp = x;
      x = y;    
      y = tmp;  

}
```

Every assignment expression costs 1 (in terms of time complexity), so T(n) = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3 which means O(1). But what can I say about this function?

```
void swap(...)

{

      tmp = x;
      x = y;    
      y = tmp;  

      printf("Value of x: %d", x);
      printf("Value of y: %d", y);

}
```

Can I say that T(n) is still O(1) in this case?

Comment: It's O(n), with n being the length of output. Probably. Given lots of assumptions, some more and some less reasonable.

Comment: It's O(1) because the set of fixed-width integers is finite…

Comment: snprintf (...) returns the number of characters that _would_ be printed, even if fewer characters are actually printed. So the time for snprintf (buffer, 1, "%s", some string) is unlimited, with at most 1 byte printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is strange to try to evaluate time complexity of `printf()` as it's a blocking input/output operation that performs some text processing *and* performs a write operation via a series of `write()` system calls through an intermediate buffering layer.

The best guess about the text processing part is that the whole input string must be read and all arguments are processed so unless there's some black magic, you can assume O(n) to the *number of characters*. You're usually not expected to feed the format argument of `printf()` dynamicaly and therefore the size is known, therefore finite and therefore the complexity is indeed O(1).

On the other hand, the time complexity of a blocking output operation is not bounded. In blocking mode, all `write()` operations return either with an error or with at least one byte written. Assuming the system is ready to accept new data in a constant time, you're getting O(1) as well.

Any other transformations also occur lineary to the typically constant size of the format or result string, so with a number of assumptions, you can say it's O(1).

Also your code suggests that the output only occurs to actually test the functionality and shouldn't be considered part of the computation at all. The best way is to move the I/O out of the functions you want to consider for the purpose of complexity, e.g. to the `main()` function to stress that the input and output is there just for testing out the code.

Implementation of the O(1) swap function without I/O:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

Alternative implementation without a temporary variable (just for fun):

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    *a ^= *b;
    *b ^= *a;
    *a ^= *b;
}
```

Implementation of the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a = 3, b = 5;

    printf("a = %d; b = %d\n", a, b);
    swap(&a, &b);
    printf("a = %d; b = %d\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is really a sensible question to ask, because `printf`'s behavior is mostly implementation-defined. C doesn't place any restrictions on what the system decides to do once it hits `printf`. It does have a notion of a *stream*. Section 7.21 of the C11 standard states that `printf` acts over a stream.

C lets the implementation do anything that it wants with streams after they're written to (7.21.2.2):

> Characters may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to conform to differing conventions for representing text in the host environment. Thus, there need not be a one- to-one correspondence between the characters in a stream and those in the external
>   representation

So your call to `printf` is allowed to write out 1 TB whenever a `char` is printed, and 1 byte whenever an `int` is printed.

The standard doesn't even require that the write happen when `printf` is actually called (7.21.3.3):

> When a stream is unbuffered, characters are intended to appear from the source or at the
>   destination as soon as possible. Otherwise characters may be accumulated and
>   transmitted to or from the host environment as a block. When a stream is fully buffered, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when
>   a buffer is filled... Support for these characteristics is
>   implementation-defined.

And [the standard doesn't specify whether `stdout` is buffered or unbuffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723795/is-stdout-line-buffered-unbuffered-or-indeterminate-by-default). So C allows `printf` to do pretty much whatever it feels like once you ask it for a write.

Comment: Actually, `printf` is not a system call for any reasonable meaning of system call. `printf` is a *library function* defined by the C standards (e.g. ISO 9899:1999) and is typically implemented within the libc.

Comment: @FUZxxl My understanding is that IO is always going to be something you ask the OS to do, at the lowest level. I've edited to try to address your comment, though, let me know if it's still inaccurate.

Comment: It's better now. `printf` is usually (i.e. always) implemented as a function that interpretes the formatting string, creates output and then proceeds to send this output to `stdout` using functions like `fwrite()` and `fputc()`. The implementation of the `FILE` API in turn uses system calls (on unixoid systems `write()`) to send the data to the operating system. `printf` itself should never call the operating system directly.

Comment: Also, the common definition for *system call* is *a function call into the operating system, a function whose mere purpose is to call into the operating system with no preprocessing of arguments*.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the complexity of `printf()` is O(N) with N being the number of characters that are output. And this amount is not necessarily a small constant, as in these two calls:

```
printf("%s", myString);
printf("%*d", width, num);
```

The length of `myString` does not necessarily have an upper bound, so complexity of the first call is O(`strlen(myString)`), and the second call will output `width` characters, which can be expected to take O(`width`) time.

However, in most cases the amount of output written by `printf()` will be bounded by a small constant: format strings are generally compile time constants and computed field widths as above are rarely used. String arguments are more frequent, but oftentimes allow giving an upper limit as well (like when you output a string from a list of error messages). So, I'd wager that at least 90% of the real world `printf()` calls are O(1).

Answer (score -3):

The time complexity means not how many time required to run particular program. The time complexity is measured in number of frequencies it requires to run. Now if you are considering the simple printf() statement then obviously time complexity will be O(1).

Refer:
[Time Complexity For Algorithm](http://www.studytonight.com/data-structures/time-complexity-of-algorithms)

Comment: "The number of frequency it requires to run" doesn't mean anything. Nor does "the number of frequencies it requires to run." Frequency is a measure of how many times per second something happens. Saying "the number of times per second it requires to run" is meaningless.

Comment: And the premise is wrong, as I state in my answer: the C standard doesn't require that `printf` have any particular time complexity.

Comment: I'd told that calculating Time complexity for algorithm and the frequency doesn't mean 1/T like that. It means How frequent the statement is. refer: http://www.cprogramdevelop.com/2489870/

Comment: avinash, printf ("%s", s) would have complexity at least O (strlen (s)). Not O (1).

Comment: @Avinash The link you posted is wrong. It's incorrect English and incorrect computer science. It's mostly gibberish.

Comment: "With the increase in module n, proportional to the algorithm execution time of the growth rate and the growth rate of f (n), so the smaller the f (n), the time complexity of the algorithm is the lower, the higher the efficiency of the algorithm." -- this doesn't mean anything at all. It reads the output of one of those fake "generate a CS paper" programs.

Comment: @Patrick: I'd not followed with that link but i'd read that in book. But let it be cause i think i'd compared the Book's logic over here.

Comment: @Avinash Are you suggesting that if I write a 10-deep `for` loop giving O(n^10), as long I wrap it in a single function call, then because I only call the function once, it suddenly becomes O(1)?