# Assignments to malloced string behaving wierd

Tags: c

Here are the codes, it's C code. And please explain return value of ="string"

```
    char * p = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    p = "hello";   
    *(p+1) = '1';
    printf("%s", p);
    free(p);
```

Comment: you're trying to write to a write-only address because the string "hello" is in your .ro data section. Furthermore, what do you want to achieve with this code?

Comment: 1) You have memory leak since you lose the pointer `p` returned by `malloc()` 2) you are trying to modify a string literal - that is UB.

Comment: Line 3: [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/164194/33499)

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong with it?

Comment: and you are freeing a ro memory section. too many problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that `p = "hello";` does not copy any string, but just sets the pointer `p` to become the *address* of the 6 bytes literal string `"hello"`.  To copy a string use `strncpy` or `strcpy` (read [strncpy(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncpy.3.html) ...) but be scared of [buffer overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

So you do

```
 char * p = malloc(100);
```

which allocates a memory zone capable of holding 100 bytes. Let's pretend that `malloc` succeeded (read [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)...) and returned the address 0x123456 for example (often, that concrete address is not reproducible from one run to the next, e.g. because of [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)).

Then you assign `p = "hello";` so you forgot the address 0x123456 (you've got now a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)), and you put in `p` the address of the 6 bytes literal string `"hello"` (let's imagine it is 0x2468a).

Later the machine executes the code for `*(p+1) = '1';` so you are trying to replace the `e` character (at address 0x2468b) inside literal `"hello"` by `1`. You get a [segmentation violation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) (or some other [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)), since that literal string sits in constant read only memory (e.g. the [text segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) of your executable, at least on Linux).

A better code might be:

```
 #define MY_BUFFER_LEN 100
 char *p = malloc(MY_BUFFER_LEN);
 if (!p) { perror("malloc for p"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 strncpy(p, "hello", MY_BUFFER_LEN); /// you could do strcpy(p, "hello")
 *(p+1) = '1';
 printf("%s", p);
 free(p);
```

and if you are lucky (no memory failure) that would *much later* output `h1llo` (the output will happen only when `stdout` becomes flushed since it is [buffered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer), e.g. by some later call to `fflush`). So don't forget to call

```
 fflush(NULL);
```

after the previous code chunk. Read [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html), [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html).

A generic advice is to read [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of every function that you are using (even [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) ...).

Regarding `printf` and related functions, since `stdout` is often [line buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3746795/841108), in practice I strongly recommend to end every format control string with `\n` -e.g. `printf("%s\n", p);` in your code; when you don't do that (there are some cases where you don't want to...) think twice and perhaps comment your code.

Don't forget to compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then learn how to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: Is this: `*(p+1) = '1';` not simply just a reassignment of the value for the second `char` in the array?, and perfectly legal?

Comment: @ryyker: it's not legal if you're trying to write to read-only memory.

Comment: What is so?...  You assert above it is a segmentation fault.  But I do not believe it is.  It is not sitting in constant read only memory, it is sitting on the heap, in malloc'ed memory.

Comment: What makes it read-only memory.  I must have missed that part.

Comment: @ryyker: `"hello"` is not malloc'ed. OP's `p` is pointing to a string literal `"hello"`.

Comment: Oh, Yep, I see now.  I had in my mind `p` after having used strcpy() to assign "hello", my bad.

Comment: @Basile: Wouldn't simply using `printf("%s\n",p)` do the trick?

Comment: Yers, it does. So I improved my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does.

"hello" is behind the scenes a pointer to a static array of six chars, most likely write protected.

When you assign it to p, the pointer that malloc returned is lost, instead p now contains a pointer to that static array of six chars.

The assigment to p+1 may crash, or may not crash, but whatever it does, it is undefined behaviour and will cause trouble.

free (p) tries to free a static array of six chars. That isn't going to work. Again, undefined behaviour, and an immediate crash if you are lucky.

Answer (score 1):

There are problems in nearly each line:
1) In the first line you are assigning to `p` the address of newly allocated memory. which is OK
2) In the next line you overwrite it with an address of some static string. Which is bad, since the allocated memory is "lost", thus causing memory leak.
3) In the third line you are trying to overwrite something in the static string location, which might be read only, which is bad. 
4) In the last line you are trying to free the memory at the string's location, which is memory violation.

Answer (score 0):

1)  In C it is incorrect cast the return of malloc()  (C++, okay to cast)
2)  Once allocated memory, assigning a value to `p` is not done by `=`.
strcpy(p, "hello"); is better.
3)  Once assigned correctly, using `strcpy()`, *(p+1) = '1' is the same as p[1] = '1', and will result in "h1llo".

By the way, using the line *(p+1) = '1' *AFTER* using p = "hello" to assign the value hello (instead of `strcpy()`) will cause problems, as described by @gnasher, @Basile and others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what pointers are.

In C, there is no variable that can store a string. Instead the strings are stored in arrays of chars. In order to be able to handle such an array, you use a variable (called pointer) that stores the memory address of the first element of the array. Also, strings have a special character (the nul character) the indicate where they end, but that's not relevant here.

In the code you posted, you allocate memory to store 100 chars (this is usually 100 bytes) and get a pointer to the first element of this memory region, called p (for further reading: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)).

Whenever you use a string literal, some memory gets allocated and it gets stored in that memory region. When you assign it to p, p now points to the first element of the new memory region, that stores the string (so you've lost the memory allocated you malloc -> memory leak). Now, you try to modify the string pointed at by p. This won't work, as the string literals are stored as constant strings. And after that, you try to free the memory of this string, which is not possible. All of these mistakes generate runtime errors and are not very easy to detect and fix. In order to be able to achieve what you want, use a function like strcpy to copy the string from the read-only memory region to your pointer:

```
strcpy(p, "string");
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in C are arrays, and you can't use = to assign values to arrays, only to indexed elements of arrays.  For copying string data, use `strcpy()` or `strncpy()`.  Your code could look like:

```
char *p = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
strcpy(p, "hello");   
*(p+1) = '1';
printf("%s", p);
free(p);
```

Try that. The difference is that `p = "hello"` will set the pointer p to point to the constant string "hello", overwriting the pointer to the 100-byte memory block you just allocated.  The `free(p);` call below will fail because you're passing a pointer not returned by an allocation function, even if the system you're using doesn't give a write fault on attempting to modify constant data.

If you ever do need to point a pointer at a constant string (it happens), be sure you declare the pointer as `const char *`.  This is required in C++.  I don't know if it's required in newer versions of C, but it's a Real Good Idea in any case.