# Raspberry Pi: printf() doesn't work with wiringPi

Tags: c, printf, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm trying a simple code that using wiringPi as here:

```
#include<wiringPi.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int i;

    wirintPiSetup();
    pinMode(0,OUTPUT);   //a single LED
    pinMode(8,INPUT);    //tactile switch

    for(;;){
        delay(500);
        //push tactile switch and LED is turning on
        if(digitalRead(8)) digitalWrite(0,0);
        else digitalWrite(0,1);
        printf("%d",digitalRead(8));
    }
}
```

I expected a result of printf() is output to console, 
but it doesn't work.
printf() couldn't run in same time with wiringPi APIs?

no warnings at compile. and CPU consumption is always under 4%.
running on Raspbian.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The `printf` function should definitely work.

Comment: Have you tried put printf in start of your code to check if your program crashes before entering the loop?
Else try with gdb

Comment: Thanks for a mention!
now i tried put printf hello in start of code, and it doesn't work! suppose, something went wrong out of logic.
I'll try gdb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`stdout` by default is typically *line-buffered*, meaning it tries to put off writing data to the underlying file until a newline. But since you never print a newline, `stdout` will just buffer your text until it runs out of space.

You can fix this by either adding a newline in the format string (i.e. `"%d\n"`), or calling `fflush` on `stdout` after printing.

Comment: it solved! I'm Japanese, so using Japanese keyboard and it can't type backslash...lol
copy and paste backslash from website, and it works well.
thank you so much!

Comment: I originally used "/n", not "\n".   Your answer helped me figure that out.  I get a "hello world\n" from the  VS2019  remote console connected a raspberry pi target.

Comment: Drew McGowen, "stdout by default is line-buffered" --> Hmmm.  What spec says that? Certainly not the C spec.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you're right - the C standard only says "the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device." Based on https://stackoverflow.com/q/3723795/2478565, it seems like line-buffered stdout is the most common.