# text written to stdout doesn't appear until program completion

Tags: c, emscripten

In this example, I am simply printing the numbers from 0 to 9 with a delay after each.  However, instead of trickling the numbers to the output window, there is a long pause (with a "spinner" icon churning) and then all of the numbers are displayed at once (tested in both Chromium 44.0 and Firefox 40.0.3).

Is there a way to to make writes to `stdout` display immediately?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void time_waster( int reps=100 ) {
   static volatile unsigned counter=0;
   for ( int a=0; a<reps; a++ ) {
      for ( int b=0; b<1000*1000; b++ ) counter++;
   }
}

int main() {
  for ( int i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
     fprintf(stdout,"%d\n",i);
     fflush(stdout);
     time_waster();
  }
}
```

JavaScript and HTML built with:

```
emcc -Wall -Werror -o temp.html count.c
```

By the way, the combined size of the generated HTML+JavaScript for this small example is roughly 600KB (14619 lines), so debugging in the browser would be a non-trivial task.

Note: I had the same issue with `std::cout` in C++ (also with explicit flushing), but decided to write the question in C as a simplification of the problem.

---

I have discovered that the output is displayed as intended if I run the program with [node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js):

```
node temp.js
```

So the problem only occurs when running in a browser using the HTML generated by the Emscripten compiler.

Comment: Have you tried it with normal C compiler without any exotics?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if `fflush` is simply mapped to a no-op. This is just a wild guess though.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I hadn't bothered to do that previously because I know this should work.  But since you asked, I did -- and it works as expected (a visible delay after each number).

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/2770) you go, I guess..

Comment: Maybe fix by providing a custom implementation of the [Module object](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/module.html).

Comment: **Note:** `-Werror` should be `-Wextra` to get all the bang for your buck.

Comment: [Why does my HTML app hang?](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#why-does-my-html-app-hang)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps that behavior is by design, thus the main loop needs to be replaced by `emscripten_set_main_loop` or Emterpreter-Async.

https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Emterpreter

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>

void time_waster( int reps=100 ) {
   static volatile unsigned counter=0;
   for ( int a=0; a<reps; a++ ) {
      for ( int b=0; b<1000*1000; b++ ) counter++;
   }
}

int main() {
  for ( int i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
     fprintf(stdout,"%d\n",i);
     fflush(stdout);
     emscripten_sleep(0);
     time_waster();
  }
}
```

`em++ -Wall -Werror -o temp.html count.cpp -s EMTERPRETIFY=1 -s EMTERPRETIFY_ASYNC=1 -s EMTERPRETIFY_WHITELIST="['_main']" -Oz`

Comment: This solves the problem.  Note: [You need a web server to run it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local).

Answer (score 3):

From the [emscripten source](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/667dcd241886fdb878e248d95d8e03abb09c80b7/src/library.js#L2234) we find that [`fflush`](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/2770) does nothing.

Comment: +1 for the good data.  However, there seems to be some ambiguity in the linked pages about whether or not the no-op `fflush()` is relevant in the case where the strings include `\n` (as mine do).  In other words, `stdout` might/should be "line-buffered" as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723795/is-stdout-line-buffered-unbuffered-or-indeterminate-by-default), and therefore each line should appear immediately, regardless of `fflush()`.  I really only added the `fflush()` to prevent commenters from suggesting it.