# no output in console window:codeblocks

Tags: c++

Heya I have installed codeblocks..on windows7
codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup-TDM-GCC-481.exe
my program is building but after executing i am getting a console window only with a cursor and no output. I tried it with many other programs but the same thing is happening.
I have also set all the settings to default and have also re installed codeblocks.
I am attaching snippet of the console window for the program code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printf("helloworld%s")
   return 0;
 }
```

Even the default program was not working because it failed to recognize iostream.
PLease help..!

Comment: How about removing `%s` ?

Comment: 1 - that code won't even compile due to the missing `;` after the printf line (and no compilation, no execution and thus no output so that might be your first problem), but even if it would compile 2 - `"helloworld%s"` is invalid as you fail to pass an extra string argument

Comment: you can `#include <iostream>` and print `std::cout << "helloworld" << std::endl;`

Comment: @BoPersson yes i use avast antivirus but i tried to execute by switching it off temporarily still no help!

Comment: @fvu thanks for it i removed%s and also put a semicolon still it compiled but didn't show output!

Comment: @gomons compiler is failing to recognise iostream thereby i shifted to stdio.h

Comment: "compiler is failing to recognize iostream" - is your file called somethign ending in `.cpp` ?

Answer (score 1):

1. You forgot the `;` at the end of the `printf()` line, you should have a syntax error when compiling.
2. The `%s` doesn't mean any sense if there is no additionnal argument. It is used when you want to print a string stored in a variable. Example:

`int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char str[] = "world!";
    printf("Hello %s\n", str);
}`

will print "Hello world!".

3. Unless you know what you're doing, you should add a `\n` at the end of the printed line (before output on `stdout` are buffered, and printed when the buffer is full : [Is stdout line buffered, unbuffered or indeterminate by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723795/is-stdout-line-buffered-unbuffered-or-indeterminate-by-default))