# Swift cannot output when using NSTimer

Tags: swift, stdout, nstimer, mainrunloop

I tried output to STDOUT every second by using `NSTimer`.

I wrote the following code and saved it as sample.swift.

```
#!/usr/bin/swift

import AppKit

class Foo : NSObject {
  override init() {
    super.init()
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "bar", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  }

  func bar() {
    print("buz")
  }
}

let h = Foo()

// Output successful
// while true {
//   print("Foo!")
// }

NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().run()
```

Then, I executed the following command and can see `buz`.

```
okada@iyokan$ ./sample.swift
buz
buz
buz
buz
```

So, I executed the following command but I cannot see any `buz`.

```
okada@iyokan$ ./sample.swift > sample.log # wait 5 seconds
okada@iyokan$ cat sample.log
okada@iyokan$
```

By the way, I tried while loop version (activated comment out the above code) then I could get `buz` by two procedures.

Why I could not get any `buz`?
Please teach me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a "normal" behaviour of the stdio library. A file descriptor
can be "buffered", which means that the result of all `printf()` and
other output operations goes to an internal buffer first. When that
buffer reaches a certain size (e.g. 8KB), its contents is written to the actual
file.

There are three modes: "unbuffered" (all output is written to the file
immediately), "line buffered" (output is collected until a newline
characters is printed),
and "fully buffered".

According to [Is stdout line buffered, unbuffered or indeterminate by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723795/is-stdout-line-buffered-unbuffered-or-indeterminate-by-default):

> Unix convention is that stdin and stdout are line-buffered when associated with a terminal, and fully-buffered (aka block-buffered) otherwise.

This explains why you see the output of each print operation 
immediately when the output goes to the terminal, but not when
output is redirected to a file.

With

```
print("buz")
fflush(stdout)
```

you can force the output to be written to the file immediately.
Alternatively, you can set standard output into line buffering mode
by calling

```
setlinebuf(stdout)
```

before anything is printed.