# Swift stderr and stout into single file

Tags: ios, swift, stdout, nslog, freopen

For an iPhone app, I need to collect debugging data into a file to be sent to an online service for analysis. This works fine by diverting the `stderr` output to a file handle and sending the file when appropriate. (`NSLog` output also ends up in `stderr`, so this works across the board.) The same method also works fine with `stdout`.

Here is how I do the saving to a file:

```
freopen(cStringFilePath, "a+", stderr) // or stdout
```

The above correctly returns a `UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE>` which I keep track of in order to close the file when necessary.

However, I would need **the content of both `stdout` and `stderr` in *one* file**, with the correct time sequence line by line.

The reason for this is that I am trying to debug a third party framework which produces diagnostic output but writes it to `stdout` rather to `stderr`.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just calling `freopen` twice? Once with `stderr` and once with `stdout`? I think that worked fine for my purposes when I tried it.

Comment: No, it seems it will only capture the one you used last.

Comment: Correction. It seems to be working. Wow. But is it safe? What if the two streams try to access the file at the same time?

Comment: Yeah, it should be "safe", i.e. It shouldn't crash, but you may get output interleaved because of buffering rules. I think you can modify how buffering happens on those file descriptors, but I'm not sure how off the top of my head.

Comment: @Mundi:  `setlinebuf()` can be used to set stdout/stderr to line buffering mode ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34744179/1187415)). By default, both are unbuffered when writing to a file.