# fgets doesn't stop reading user input

Tags: c, fgets

I found some challenge on reddit to make a program which will sum up all DnD dice rolls. Number of throws is unlimited therefore I created this while loop.

I used fgets to input the string,  (I can't input only integers because the input is for example 1d3, where 1 is number of dice thrown, and 3 is number of sides of the dice thrown.)

When the user is prompted to input dice, fgets never stops reading user input.

For example:

```
To end inputting dice type 0
1d3 
1d4
1d5
0
0
^C
```

Main function:

```
int main(void)
{
    char input[MAXSIZE];
    int sum = 0;
    printf("To end inputting dice type 0\n");
    while(*(input) != 0);
    {
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        printf("Debug: input = ");
        puts(input);
        printf("\n");
        sum += dice(input);
        printf("Debug: sum = %d\n", sum);
    }
    printf("Sum of dice rolls is %d.", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have found the culprit (also notice Sourav's correct mention of `0` not being the same as `'0'` in your `while` condition); but there is more that can be improved. You should check that `input[ strlen( input ) -1 ] == '\n'`. If it isn't, the line you read was incomplete. Also: 1) `#include <stdio.h>` missing. 2) `MAXSIZE` undeclared. 3) function `dice` undeclared. Please use [mcve]s.

Comment: @DevSolar `input[ strlen( input ) -1 ] == '\n'` sets up a hacker exploit when the first character read  is a _null character_.

Comment: @chux: Sheesh... good point. I'll let my comment stand though, as the general gist still holds. (Good thing I never wrote C in places where this would have mattered...)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the literal value of the character input `0` is not `0`. In [ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/), it is 48 (decimal).

Try

```
 while(*(input) != '0')  // (1) - use the character literal form
                         // (2) remove the ;
```

That said, the [standard output is usually line buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3746795/2173917). You need to force a flush if you want to see the outputs in the terminal. You can do that by either

- add a newline

  ```
   printf("Debug: input = \n");
  ```
- use `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: It is a good point that it would make it so that hitting enter without entering a die type would cause it to end if the rest was working, but it's doesn't seem to be the real issue.

Comment: @ThomasJager Yes, I added that part, too.

Comment: @user3121023 Right you are, missed that. Need to read more carefully. One bug is not enough. :(

Comment: Detail: C calls `'0'` a _character constant_, not a literal.

Comment: The code should initialize `input` before testing whether `input[0]` is `'0'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
while(fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) != NULL)
```

or

```
while(fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin))
```

Comment: It doesn't fix the bug.

Comment: @LovreGusar Did you also delete the `;` at the end of the `while()`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was really simple and such a beginner mistake I feel shameful for even asking the question.

The semicolon after the while loop.

Thanks all for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
char input[MAXSIZE] = { 0 }; // initialise input!
// otherwise you get to here and access an uninitialised variable:
while(*(input) != 0); // <--- and a semicolon right there!!! Remove that!
```

In fact I think the loop you want is `while (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) && strcmp(input, "0\n"))`... note that I've hoisted the `fgets` into the loops control expression.

You should probably do a check after calling `fgets` to ensure a newline is read, for example

```
while (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) && strcmp(input, "0\n")) {
    size_t n = strcspn(input, "\n");
    if (input[n] == '\n') input[n] = '\0';
    else assert(input[n] == '\0'), // #include <assert.h>
         fscanf(stdin, "%*[^\n]"),
         fgetc(stdin);
```

There's no undefined behaviour associated with reading unsigned integers when using `fscanf`, so if you only plan on using positive values you can use that instead of `fgets` if you wish, i.e.

```
unsigned dice_count, dice_sides;
while (fscanf(stdin, "%ud%u", &dice_count, &dice_sides) == 2) {
    printf("You chose to roll %u times with dice that contain %u sides\n", dice_count, dice_sides);
}
```