# A bug of print function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, buffering, output-buffering

```
from socket import *
from threading import Thread

udp_socket = None
dest_ip = ''
dest_port = 0


def send():
    while True:
        content = input('<<<')
        udp_socket.sendto(content.encode(), (dest_ip, dest_port))


def recv():
    while True:
        data = udp_socket.recvfrom(1024)
        content, address = data
        ip, port = address
        print('\r>>>[%s %d] %s' % (ip, port, content.decode()))
        print('<<<', end='')


def main():
    global udp_socket, dest_ip, dest_port
    udp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    udp_socket.bind(('', 7788))

    dest_ip = input('Please enter the IP: ')
    dest_port = int(input('Please enter the port: '))

    ts = Thread(target=send)
    tr = Thread(target=recv)
    ts.start()
    tr.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When `recv()` is called, `print('<<<', end='')`
is not printed out. Is there anybody who knows the reason behind it? By the way, I run it in both of Pycharm IDE and Linux OS. But the bug appears in both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not a bug. Your `stdout` stream is *line buffered* and will not be auto-flushed until a `\n` newline is printed. The data has been written to the buffer, but won't be written to your screen until the buffer is flushed.

Add `flush=True` to the `print()` call to force a manual flush:

```
print('<<<', end='', flush=True)
```

`stdout` is [commonly line-buffered when connected to a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723795/is-stdout-line-buffered-unbuffered-or-indeterminate-by-default), block-buffered otherwise; line-buffering strikes a balance between avoiding too-frequent updates of the terminal and getting information to the user in a timely manner.

Comment: Why does buffering happen here?

Comment: @Jerence: because that's the default setting for stdin/stdout. It makes sense to wait for a newline character in the fast majority of use cases and it makes screen updates more efficient.

Comment: So in which situation does it happen? I run print(x, end='') many times, but this case never happens.

Comment: @Jerence: **where** are you running it? In the Python interpreter? And it matters if `x` contains a newline character of its own.

Comment: Yes, in the python interpreter. But in this case, string “<<<“ does not contain its own newline character.

Comment: @Jerence: in the REPL, the prompt is printed right after. That contains a newline, so the buffer is flushed.