# Printf not working if there isn't \n at the end

Tags: c, io, printf, newline

Does the `printf()` function in C need a `\n` at the end in order to work ?

I tried printing out a simple statement without a newline at the end and it didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The likely reason is [a line buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723795/is-stdout-line-buffered-unbuffered-or-indeterminate-by-default) `stdout`, (this is implementation defined so I can't be 100% sure). In these implementations the content written to the buffer won't immediately be transferred to the output.

Using `"\n"`, causes a flush of the buffer to the output and the `printf` will print the contents, the downside is that the `"\n"` will also be printed.

As an alternative, you can use [`fflush(stdout)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) if you don't want a that newline character to be printed.

> *For output streams (and for update streams on which the last operation was output), writes any unwritten data from the stream's buffer to the associated output device.*