# Should you flush after the course of each user input of loop in C?

Tags: c, input, flush

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char text[256];
    
    while (1) {
        puts("Text?");
        fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin);
        fflush(stdout); // should you flush everytime?
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

For example, if you were to create user input and print in an while loop that doesn't break, should you flush? Is it also necessary to flush stdin?

If also you would fputs in stderr, would you also have to flush stderr in this scenario?

Comment: What's the point of flushing after the `fgets`?  It would make more sense to flush after the `puts` and before the `fgets`, to make sure the prompt is displayed before waiting for user input.  But if you are actually interacting with the user on a terminal, then `stdout` is likely to be line buffered anyway, and `puts` prints a newline, so the flush is redundant.

Comment: Someone will probably give a more detailed explanation, but in general no. With some exceptions, I never manually flush `stdin` or `stdout`.

Comment: @NateEldredge If lets say you use `printf` instead of `puts`, would it still be the same?

Comment: [`fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) so never do that, period.

Comment: If your  prompt didn't have a newline then yes, you should `fflush(stdout)` (before `fgets`, not after) if you want the user to see the prompt before they have to type.  But most programs that involve significant user interaction will be using something fancier than stdio anyhow (e.g. curses) so the issue rarely arises in practice.

Comment: @NateEldredge This also implies to `stderr`, correct?

Comment: @JackMurrow: For maximum portability, yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723795/is-stdout-line-buffered-unbuffered-or-indeterminate-by-default, but on many common systems `stderr` is unbuffered by default so there is no need to `fflush` it.

Comment: @NateEldredge How about for C++?

Comment: I do not know as much about C++.  You probably should have asked about C and C++ in two separate questions as they are two separate languages.  However, for things like stdio, AFAIK C++ generally conforms to C (this is not necessarily true of other parts of the language).

Comment: @Jack, For C++, you have `tie()` set up by default on `cout` and `cin` to flush `stdout` right before `stdin` is used.

Comment: @chris Thank you I'll make a separate question for C++

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush only when there are pending bytes in the buffer, that is, if there is not a newline inside `text`. Anyway, what you should flush is `stdin` (not `stdout`):

```
    fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin);
    // fflush(stdout); // should you flush everytime? --> NOPS
    if (strchr(text, '\n') == NULL)
    {
        int c;
        // Flush stdin
        while (((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') && (c != EOF));
    }
```

Comment: Someone in the comments say `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, and to never do that. So I am confused, then how would you flush stdin?

Comment: Yes, `fflush(stdin)` is UB, use `while (((c == fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') && (c != EOF));`  instead.

Comment: Is it possible to do without `fgetc`?

Comment: You can use `c = getchar() ...`  but notice that `getchar()` is usually implemented as a macro: `#define getchar() fgetc(stdin)` so you end up using `fgetc` anyway.