# Subprocess.popen() Doesn't Work With Swift

Tags: python, swift, subprocess, popen

I want to `subprocess.popen()` a Swift program with Python 3.

parent.py:

```
import subprocess

#p = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'sub.py'], universal_newlines = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, bufsize=1)

p = subprocess.Popen(['swift', 'sub.swift'], universal_newlines = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, bufsize=1)

while True:
    a=input('command:')
    if not a:
        print(p.stdout.readline())
    else:
        p.stdin.write(a+'\n')
```

sub.swift

```
while true {
    print(readLine()!)
}
```

It doesn't work. `p.stdout.readline()` stalls.

If I change the command to `['python3', 'sub.py']` and have

sub.py

```
while True:
    print(input())
```

It works:

```
> python3 parent.py
command:a
command:[enter]
a

command:asdf
command:[enter]
asdf
```

Why is this? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flushing standard output worked for me:

```
import Darwin
while true {
    print(readLine()!)
    fflush(stdout)
}
```

I'm not too familiar with Python, but my guess is that the Python `print` probably automatically flushes.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot. Can you please elaborate on flushing? Is the program not writing to stdout directly?

Comment: @JohnHao Correct, stdout is buffered in this particular case (I don't know how big the buffer is), since your python program isn't able to read anything without flushing. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723795/is-stdout-line-buffered-unbuffered-or-indeterminate-by-default